# Difference between two synchronization methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a doubt that is somewhat confusing me in java thread synchronization, if I have a shared memory zone, what is the difference between using wait/notify/notifyAll in the synchronized methods and declaring an Object (Object myObj) and using myObj.wait, as far as I understand both somewhat achieve the same.

In other words:
This

```
public class ThreadSignal{
    protected boolean isDataAvailable = false;
    public void synchronized waitUntilComplete(){
       if(isDataAvailable == false){
           wait();
       }
    }
    public void synchronized complete(){
       isDataAvailable = true;
       notify();
    }
}
```

vs This

```
private Object notEmpty = new Object();
private Object notFull = new Object();
public synchronized E take() {
        //some code
            notEmpty.wait()
        //some code
        notFull.notifyAll();
}
```

Is the difference in that the first one locks the whole object thus no other thread gets access to that shared region and in the second one we get more flexibility in what we want to lock down?

Second question since putting this in a comment is hard (editing main post for it):

I have a problem Im trying to resolve and figuring the best way to architect the class, the problem is as follows there's an airport with a queue (shared region) and three threads (pilot,hostess and passenger), the hostess is basically the check in from the airport.

The passenger first enters queue and waits for the operation checkDocuments from the hostess (so it gets in a blocking/waiting state) then it presents the plane ticket and waits for the operation waitForNextPassenger of the hostess to procceed inside the plane. The hostess on the other hand wakes up by the operation waitInQueue of the passenger (when it first enters the queue), checks the passenger and then gets in another wait state that waits for the passengers documents and then checks in the passenger.

Given this I have defined these blocking variables:
waitInQueue
checkDocuments
showingDocuments
waitForNextPassenger

Given what you said in the comment, I suppose a good approach would be to make each of these an object and for example in the thread passenger lifecycle it would call the method WaitInQueue that would wait for the object checkDocuments (checkDocuments.wait) and the hostess would for example checkDocuments.notify

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Well, they are just different.  One difference is that the first locks the whole object, and therefore the lock is external and visible to anyone with a reference to that object.  But also the locking strategy seems different (two locks versus one) and also `notify()` and `notifyAll()` do different things.

Comment: Well the examples I placed are different but I could do the first example by tecnically doing Object isDataAvailable; then instead of wait do isDataAvailable.wait and then isDataAvailable.notify. What would be the main difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A synchronized method:

```
public void synchronized f() {...}
```

is identical to:

```
public void f() {
  synchronized(this) {
  ...
  }
}
```

which is different from:

```
private Object obj=new Object()

public void f() {
  synchronized(obj) {
    ...
   }
}
```

The synchronized method uses `this`, which means any other synchronized method working on the same object will wait until the current synchronized method returns. When you use a separate object with a synchronized block, the synchronized block will wait until the current synchronized block using the same object exits. So with the second approach, you can do:

```
public void f() {
   synchronized(obj) {
     ...
   }
   // Do stuff
   synchronized(obj) {
    ...
   }
}
```

That is, you can control the mutual exclusion in a more granular way.

The second approach also allows you to lock multiple objects.

You have to be careful about `wait`/`notify` when you're using the second approach. You can call `obj.wait()` if you are holding the lock for `obj`, meaning you are in a synchronized block `synchronized(obj)`. When `wait` is called, the synchronized block will relinquish the lock on that object. Then, another thread can use `obj.notify()` to send notifications to waiting threads.

Comment: So say I have a shared region that is going to be shared by three threads and that the shared region has multiple "signals" that are going to be used by the threads, its better the more granular approach I would assume?

Comment: I don't understand the part about "multiple signals". Maybe you can update the question to include this part?

Comment: Editted the main post!

Comment: You seem to be confusing the program state with locks. As far as I can tell, you have one shared resource, the queue, and you need to synchronize on that. You need to lock it when passengers arrive, and then one passenger is selected for processing.

Comment: Ahh seems I am indeed mixing it up, how can I assure a sequence of events then? Since if I have for example 10 passengers waiting for the lock on the shared region, the hostess notifies all of them to try and check in with a notifyAll , one of them goes for the check in and waits for the hostess yet again to notify him, if the hostess now notifies (so releases the shared area) again won't it possibly wake up one of the other passenger threads and end up in situation with two threads checking in?

Comment: Do you have separate threads for each passenger? What does that thread do? Or, do you have passenger objects with a producer thread, and a processor thread (hostess) processing from a queue? You might be modeling this in a way that's really hard to implement.